# Best practice to block out a user account (for a specified time) on multiple failed Sign-in Attempts - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am currently doing it this way,

```
if params[:username].blank? # If fields are blank
   flash.now.alert = "Please Provide a Username to Login"
   render :new

elsif !User.run_lockout_mechanism params[:username] # This returns a boolean on whether
                                                    # a user can attempt another log in
                                                    # or not
   flash.now.alert = "Login not allowed for " + AppConfig.gettimeout.to_s + "minute(s)"
   render :new


else

   if user
      redirect_back_or_to dashboard_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
      User.reset params[:username] # resetting the database values

   else

      flash.now.alert = "Username or password was invalid"
      render :new

   end

end
```

1) Is this the right practice to follow in MVC?

2) Is there a more 'railsy' way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This seem to be an ok solution, but if you want a more "railsy" way, take a look at solutions like [Authlogic](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/Session/BruteForceProtection/Config#consecutive_failed_logins_limit-instance_method). [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) is pretty nice as well with its [Lockable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable) module.